# Plotting 1/(x^2) - graph looks weird near x = 0

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm a beginner to LaTeX, so the amount of variables I can change to modify a graph/plot get confusing. I found similar questions on the site, however all of them propose different solutions with completely different arguments passed to TikZ.

I found the look and feel of the following very nice:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw[->] (0.,0) -- (5,0) node[right] {$x$};
   \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,5) node[above] {$y$};
   \draw[scale=0.5,domain=0:4,smooth, variable=\x,black] plot ({\x},{1/(\x*\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This works fine for a parabola, but I wanted to graph `f(x) = 1/x^2`, which starts behaving weird near `x = 0` because the values of y increase very quickly. How can I solve this and plot it so that it fits onto the set of axes I defined?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I've edited your title since the TeX.SE does *not* use mathjax.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed that all the SE sites would use mathjax, I'll be sure not to do this next time.

Comment: No need to apologize! The TeX.SE site deliberately does *not* use mathjax since its users are generally more interested in the LaTeX code itself rather than in how it might be rendered on-screen by mathjax.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is how you can do this with `tikz` as well as with `pgfplots` (which is what I would recommend you use):

[image]

### Notes:

- You have to be careful about division by zero, especially with `tikz`. With `pgfplots` there are ways to handle such cases more elegantly. So, I have changed the domain slightly below to avoid this problem.
- I'd recommend using an extra pair of braces: So, instead of `\x*\x` I would recommend you get into the habit of `(\x)*(\x)`.  In this specific case it may not matter, but it does matter if you were to use `\x^2` which *may* yield incorrect results for negative values of `\x`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw[->] (0.,0) -- (5,0) node[right] {$x$};
   \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,5) node[above] {$y$};
   \draw[scale=0.5,domain=0.35:7,smooth, variable=\x,blue, thick] plot ({\x},{1/((\x)*(\x))});
\end{tikzpicture}
% ----------------
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=0,
    ymax=400,
    domain=0.05:1,
    samples=100,
    axis y line=left,
    axis x line=bottom, 
    %unbounded coords=discard,
    ]
    \addplot [red, ultra thick] ({\x},{1/((\x)*(\x))});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Why would you recommend pgfplots over tikz?
Edit: just saw your edit, I see why now.

Comment: @Howcan: `pgfplots` is _designed_ for plotting and `tikz` is intended for drawing. Once you start doing more complicated graphs you'll appreciate the controls that `pgfplots` provides.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. One last thing, in pgfplot, can I get rid of the intervals on the axes and maybe replace them with a label?

Comment: @Howcan: I't be better if you posted a follow up question with the details of how you want the axis labels treated. Otherwise you can try using `xticklabels={}`.

Answer (score 4):

More natural expression is possible in PSTricks. So, we can use `x^2` instead of `(\x)*(\x)`. Some keystrokes get saved.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=30pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}


\begin{document}
\begin{psgraph}[algebraic,Dy=25]{->}(0,0)(7,110){8cm}{6cm}
    \psplot[linecolor=blue,plotpoints=150]{.1}{6}{1/x^2}
\end{psgraph}
\end{document}
```

[image]